# Casting int to byte gives different results in Netbeans and JCreator

Tags: java, jar, casting, int, byte

**According to a comment from OP: cannot be reproduced any more**

I use NetBeans to develop my Java programs, and they work perfectly.
But when I make a JAR file of my program, it gives me different output for the same input.

I had a hard time debugging, and I found that in NetBeans when I cast `int` to `byte` the result ranges in `[-128; 128)`, while the same code in JCreator is in `[0; 256)`

How can I make the range always `[-128; 128)`?

```
private static byte[] convertHexString(String ss) {
    try{
        byte digest[] = new byte[ss.length() / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < digest.length; i++) {
            String byteString = ss.substring(2 * i, 2 * i + 2);
            int byteValue = Integer.parseInt(byteString, 16);
            digest[i] = (byte) byteValue;
        }
        // Test
        for(int i = 0; i < digest.length; ++i){
            System.out.println(digest[i]);
        }

        return digest;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in JCreator (we are talking about [this](http://jcreator.com), right?); it looks like when "upcasting" from byte to int (in `println()`), it won't carry the sign bit like required, hence your results

Comment: Not Only in ( JCreator) , but also in normal Windows environment. When I run the ( JAR ) file in Windows, it gave me the same result as same as ( JCreator ).

Comment: And what is your JDK? Is it Oracle's?

Comment: Yes. ( jdk1.8.0_25 )

Comment: I doubt that the code you run is compiled by Oracle's JDK, at the very least; try and compile it by hand from the command line. See my answer.

Comment: The bug is in your test. Please post the real method and the failing test case (don't put println and debug statements)

Comment: Worth noting that a byte range is -128 to 127. Not -127. And 0-255 (not 256) if it's unsigned.

Comment: @Raffaele I didn't even consider that, heh

Comment: The range of a byte is defined in the Java Language Specification as always -128 to -127, this is true no matter the environment or IDE you use.

Comment: @Raffaele I don't think you will need that to solve the probrem! **:|**

Comment: @0FiRE0 you have a bug in your code, and you can't understand what's wrong by yourself, otherwise you wouldn't have asked this question. When you have this kind of difficulties it's because you are looking at the wrong place, and we are here to help you fix your program. A Java byte can't be 255. Period. The bug is in the code that uses that value

Comment: @Raffaele Actually I did not make the code that uses the bytes, it is already made and it is compiled code :(, so I can't do anything with it.

Comment: All of the above has confused me. @0FiRE0 : Does the println in line 11 print values in the range 128:255??

Comment: @laune No, it will print the values of the array of bytes.

Comment: It better should! But you state that on some system these values are never negative but in the range 0:255. **Is this due to what you see from this println?** If not, what is the basis of your statement?

Comment: I put this statement to compare the bytes between ( NetBeant ) and ( JCreator )... NetBeant Gave me values between ( -127:127 ) and JCreator gave me values between ( 0:255 ).

Comment: Please, please: can't you simply say "yes" or "no" to the question in **boldface**? If your answer is "yes": do you see a change in the output when you use `Byte.toString(digest[i])` in the println statement?

Comment: @laune Firstly, I'm sorry, It seems that I didn't Understand the question properly. The answer is Yes. But Unexpectedly, today both NetBeans & JCreator Gave me the same range. ( -127:127 ) !!!!!. About `Byte.toString(digset[i])`, it also gave me the same range today. But I had another problem yesterday, That the array was **( null )**,so I couldn't try it.

Comment: I think you should remove this unfortunate question.

Answer (score 2):

It definitely looks like a bug. A `byte` ranges from -128 to 127, not 0 to 255.

Here is what I think is happening with a byte value of -1 (ie 0Xff), where it prints 255 instead:

```
public static void main(final String... args)
{
    final ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);

    // What Java would do on casting...
    buf.put((byte) 0xff);
    buf.put((byte) 0xff);
    buf.put((byte) 0xff);
    buf.put((byte) 0xff);

    buf.rewind();

    System.out.println(buf.getInt()); // -1 -- good

    buf.rewind();

    // What JCreator seems to do on casting...
    buf.put((byte) 0);
    buf.put((byte) 0);
    buf.put((byte) 0);
    buf.put((byte) 0xff);

    buf.rewind();

    System.out.println(buf.getInt()); // 255 -- WRONG
}
```

That is, when "upcasting" from byte to int, whatever Java compiler you use doesn't do what the JLS requires it to do, that is, to carry the sign bit.

I seriously doubt that the compiler/runner you use is Oracle's JDK at the command line too for that reason.

(note that a `PrintStream` has [a method to print an `int`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-int-), but not a `byte`; therefore the byte is promoted to an int)

Comment: The Output is : -1 255. in both ( NetBeans ) and ( JCreator ).

Comment: Well, this is normal, I made this test up; look carefully at the comments above each of them

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that the value from the byte[] isn't converted properly in the println (anyhow, not as you expect and the JLS has it).

You can use

```
 System.out.println(Byte.toString(digest[i]));
```

which should display -128 .. 127